# Prove formula equivalence without induction

Tags: factorial, closed-form

Consider the following formula:

$$\frac{(n-i)!}{n!}\sum_k \frac{(k-1)!}{(k-i)!} [2 \le i \le k \le n] = \frac{1}{i}$$

It's easy to prove the equality by induction over $n$ but is there also a more direct way (a continued equality, ideally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs identity is the *[Hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)* in disguise.

We write OPs identity as
\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-i)!}{n!}\sum_{k=i}^n\frac{(k-1)!}{(k-i)!}=\frac{1}{i}\qquad\qquad 2\leq i\leq n\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides of (1) with $\frac{n!}{(n-i)!(i-1)!}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=i}^n\binom{k-1}{i-1}=\binom{n}{i}\qquad\qquad 2\leq i\leq n\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Shifting the index $k$ by one results in
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=i-1}^{n-1}\binom{k}{i-1}=\binom{n}{i}\qquad\qquad 2\leq i\leq n}
> \end{align*}
> which is the *Hockey stick identity*.